# What am I doing wrong creating this Stripe charge using Flask and axios?

Tags: flask, stripe-payments

I'm using Vue in my frontend and I'm successfully calling the checkout modal and the token is being successfully created when that modal's form is sent. However, I haven't been able to actually create the charge on the backend.

It all starts with this method in my Vue component, that handles the token once the form is sent:

```
done ({token, args}) {
  // token - is the token object
  // args - is an object containing the billing and shipping address if enabled
  // do stuff...
  this.$refs.addBookModal.show();
  $backend.createStripeCharge(token.email, token)
},
```

The createStripeCharge function in backend.js is the following:

createStripeCharge (email, token) {
    console.log('create stripe charge called')

```
return $axios.post(`/resource/${email}`)
  .then(response => response.data)
  .catch(error => {
    this.error = error.message
  })   
},
```

and this is the route in Flask:

```
@api_rest.route('/resource/<string:resource_id>')
class ResourceOne(Resource):
""" Unsecure Resource Class: Inherit from Resource """

def post(token, user_email):
    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
        customer = token.id,
        amount = 2500,
        currency='usd', 
        description='25',
        recipent_email=user_email
    )
```

However I'm getting a 500 internal server error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I find one problem in the `ResourceOne`'s post method is that it has two parameters and you're passing only one at `backend.js`'s `createStripeCharge` function.

(Also, it is always helpful to other SO user if you post error log here.)